# Why I can't create Button in console window?

Tags: c, windows, window

I am trying to create a button in console window ,
with using winmain and windowproc i could create a button in console 
by just adding

```
HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
CreateWindowA("BUTTON","PLEASE...",WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0,0,50,50,hwnd,(HANDLE)2,NULL,NULL);
```

but without winmain(using following code) It shows they have been created but I don't see any button in console window

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
HWND WINAPI GetConsoleWindow(void);
int main()
{
    HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    if(hwnd == NULL)
        printf("\nNo console windows\n");
    else
        printf("\nCONSOLE is there{%u}\n",hwnd);
    HWND hwndB=  CreateWindowA("BUTTON","PLEASE...",WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0,0,50,50,hwnd,(HANDLE)1,NULL,NULL);
    if(hwndB == NULL)
        printf("error creating button");
    else
        printf("\nBUTTON is there{%u}\n",hwndB);

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT  is

```
CONSOLE is there{396852}

BUTTON is there{4391896}

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.094 s
Press any key to continue.
```

WHY??

Comment: Because a CONSOLE is a stupid VGA screen that can only display ASCII characters.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, the console is not a "VGA screen" and actually displays Unicode characters in the BMP.

Comment: The thread that creates the button has to continue running and have a message loop; you can't simply create a button and exit the process. That said, I wouldn't recommend creating a cross-thread window (i.e. the parent window is owned by a different thread than the child window), with an implicit `AttachThreadInput` between your application and the console. Why do you need this?

Comment: @eryksun, you can't create a window in a console. A button is a window. A console is a "sort of" emulation of a DOS-box/VGA screen.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, one can certainly put a child button in the console window. The OP did it; I did it. The console host, conhost.exe, creates its window like any other. The interaction with clients is uniquely integrated into the Windows API and process design via the process `ConsoleHandle` and standard handles, among other aspects that make the console unique. But it's not so unique that one can't create a child window or other window with the console window as its parent. This implicitly attaches your thread's input queue to that of the console input thread. Is it a good idea? No.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, the console screen buffer is not like a "VGA screen", with 640x480 RGB pixels. It's a buffer of character cells with a sliding window, in which each cell has a 16-bit Unicode character value and 16-bit attribute value (foreground and background color from a 16-color programmable palette, though in Windows 10 it also supports 24-bit color via VT sequences) and rendered using TrueType fonts. The console also converts Windows keyboard and mouse input messages into individual key and mouse events in its input buffer, with command-line editing, aliases, and history for cooked reads.

Answer (score -1):

There should be an option within your environment that changes where the output is going to go. Instead of the project being console driven, it should be windows driven, meaning that the output needs to go to a window. This is my experience using Visual Studio (any version of it).

Comment: The question is unrelated to Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, but this would be easier if he had visual studio, which he could get for free.

Comment: No, it would still be impossible to put a GUI button in a console window.